# How to get Daydream Controller to work in AFrame

Tags: aframe

I'm going crazy trying to get daydream controls to work in a my AFrame app. I'm not sure if it's my code, or my browser... Does anyone have an example that should work with the daydream controller?

Comment: are you using the official daydream controls ? https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/daydream-controls.html

Comment: Reminder: The WebVR API in Chrome for Android is behind the origin trials program. Enable WebVR and Gamepad Extensions in chrome://flags/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be quite simple. Just use the official [daydream component](https://aframe.io/docs/0.7.0/components/daydream-controls.html):

```
<a-entity daydream-controls="hand: left"></a-entity>
<a-entity daydream-controls="hand: right"></a-entity>
```

and utilize the emited events:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("daydream-listener", {
 init: function() {
  this.el.addEventListener("trackpaddown", (e) => {
    console.log("track down: ");
    console.log(e);
  })
 }
})

<a-entity daydream-controls daydream-listener></a-entity>
```

live fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/96rbnxzp/).

Comment: This example worked for me, thank you. Turns out I have to enter and exit "VR" a few times before the controller shows up for some reason...